# Cross compiling for arm android

Tags: c++, qt, android-ndk, cross-compiling, taglib

i want to build c++ library for my android device, more specific i want to build taglib to use with my Qt project, i have a music app that uses taglib, i build it for windows and ubuntu and it works as expected, but now i want to cross compile taglib to use on my android phone, i searched hours to find the solution, i found some article about toolchain file and manual cmake option but none of them worked for me,
i tried to set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME to android and set other Cmake option like below:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
message("this is host system ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} {CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/sub/Downloads/android/android-ndk-r20)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_static)
```

and when i check the generated .so file with **file** command it show my system info like below:

```
libmylib.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4245460a39baea2cbd1f28c3a2fd8037b07fe995, with debug_info, not stripped
```

so can anyone give me some link or help to do this?

> ** update

my cmake command is like below:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=ANDROID -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/sub/Downloads/android-ndk-r21/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
```

now i use new ndk and use it android.toolchain.cmake file but the output say it doesn't use it:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android
```

my new CMakeLists.txt is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)


project(addlib CXX)
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
# message("this is host system ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME} ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}")
# set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
# set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
# set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/sub/Downloads/android/android-ndk-r20)
# set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_static)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS true)
add_library(mylib main.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
message(${CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING})
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/)
```

make command output with verbose on is same as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android -B/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android/CMakeFiles /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
make -f CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
cd /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
make -f CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.so
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++ -fPIC -g  -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so -o libmylib.so CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/main.cpp.o 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
[100%] Built target mylib
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/sub/Documents/Projects/cpp/build-for-android/CMakeFiles 0
```

thank you

Comment: What is libmylib? To me it looks like you're mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: your Toolchain file seems ok. however can you give your cmake command? and may be the output of your make command with verbose mode activated?

Comment: Here is the link you are looking for: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld it is not a big library, just trying to create a library to test build and compile process on android, consist of an include file with a class inside it and a source file for class implementation, the library works fine on my ubuntu machine when i build it for android and i know it should not work.

Comment: @yflelion thanks you, i just added cmake command, cmake file and make file output with verbose on.

Comment: @MaximSkvortsov thank you maxim, i tried to use it with toolchain file but it doesn't care about toolchain file and CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING is off,please take a look in question because i update it and add more information.

Comment: Your library was compiled with g++. This problem occurs because your toolchain file was not used  by cmake, probably because your project is not clean ( already build for x86). you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757506/cmake-toolchain-file-was-not-used-by-the-project.

Comment: @yflelion thanks bro, your answer solved my problem